# CSS or Javascript is not showing up on apache web server

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am importing all of my website files onto my server and it is displaying the index.html as plain text and some basic images but no CSS or no JavaScript. I am running linux command line on putty connecting to my web server and I have no clue how to fix this, I have played and changed all permissions on the files also.

Comment: We're going to need more information to help you.  What errors are you getting in the browser console?  Are you getting errors in the Apache logs?

Comment: What errors do you get when requesting your css or javascript?

Comment: If you open up developer tools (F12) and refresh the page while looking at the Network tab, do you see 404 errors? Are the files in the right place?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/cec0e9c2ca909d9faa297280a370cc89

Comment: http://gyazo.com/ab8a1635952223c7750badb3fee57434

Comment: No errors, everything has been transferred from my computer to the server and all the files are on the server, so I have no clue why the files such as CSS or Javascript are not functioning.

Comment: I am sorry these errors pop up I dont know if they are relevant 
http://gyazo.com/13b77d65f39e5cff82f61f335c729f73

Comment: If I try to access http://tsgnetworks.uk.to/media/css/global18c4.css?v10 manually, I get a 403.

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file in your site?

Comment: @BenWalton I see the site works normally now. Does that mean the problem is solved? If so, how did you do it? Did our comments help? Was it a matter of permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You have errors on your page for your JS and CSS file paths. Track down this issue.

Comment: How? I don't know how I can track this issue. All of the CSS and JS is working when I manually open the website on my computer via the hosted files. But when I go onto my domain and reload the page all it shows is the text and some basic images, so I don't know how to solve this. Any help?